# Datepicker in custom widget Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, custom, widget, datepicker

Is there any chance to create a field in custom widget with datepicker?

I have a field that means end of sale and now I can type there text in spcific format only. I want to have there a datepicker (like in form). I didn't find any solution for this.

Comment: you can use calendar widget https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_calendar.html

if you share your code and tell where you are planning to add that, people might be able to help you better.

Comment: @Korbin What code can I provide? I want to create it. Now, I have only code with text inputs.

Comment: So you have to tell in which part of the shop you want to add it? in admin? checkout? product page?? where, all of these have different methods